# HTML5 Video Background not playing Safari on iPhone

Tags: html, html5-video, mobile-safari

I have the video background plugin for site origin page builder (Wordpress) and I have uploaded a background video (MP4 and WEBM formats). The file sizes are around 35mb and 17mb respectively.

I have tested on a couple of iPhones running up to date iOS with safari and the video is not autoplaying as it should (only showing fallback image).

**Video Code:**

```
<video id="so_bgvideo_5df3a8b601042" 
class="so_video_bg jquery-background-video is-playing is-visible" 
loop="" autoplay="" playsinline="" muted="" data-bgvideo="" 
poster="https://mywebsite.com/fallback-image.jpg" 
data-bgvideo-fade-in="500" data-bgvideo-pause-after="120" 
data-bgvideo-show-pause-play="true" 
data-bgvideo-pause-play-x-pos="right"
data-bgvideo-pause-play-y-pos="top" 
style="min-width: auto; min-height:auto; width: 100%; height: auto;
position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transition-duration: 500ms;">
<source src="https://mywebsite.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="https://mywebsite.com/video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

As far as I can tell the video contains the attributes required via Safari (and it plays fine on Safari desktop).

Can anyone please advise a fix to get it working on Safari mobile?

Comment: i think chrome and safari doesn't allow auto-playing of videos, it will only work in muted mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/51432617/9781954

Comment: Here's the official blog post about the restrictions in case it's helpful: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As stated in initial post I was using a `video background for site origins plugin` for `Wordpress`.

Although the plugin hadn't been updated in recent times, an update was available on GitHub here: https://github.com/BGStock/jquery-background-video/blob/master/jquery.background-video.js

Adding this new file/overwriting the old one resolved the issue on iOS. Hope this helps anyone else using this particular plugin.

Answer (score 20):

Safari doesn't allow autoplay of video on these 2 scenarios

1. when "muted" config not set
2. when iphone is in battery saving mode or in low battery

---

To achieve autoplay, enable `mute` and `autoplay` in both attribute and via js like

```
<video id="BgVideo" muted autoplay>

<script>
var bgvideo = document.getElementById("BgVideo");
bgvideo.muted = true;
bgvideo.play();
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Ganeshkumar K, this was missing from my set up (in the script section) but still doesn't work on Safari iOS???

Comment: If u could setup your code in codepen/jsfiddle and share the link, then I can look better into it.

Comment: Thanks @Ganeshkumar K. Found the resolution to the issue on GitHub, and updated in an answer.

Answer (score 13):

Just add "playsinline" along with mute and autoplay.. that's it..

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline src="..."></video>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

i think chrome and safari doesn't allow auto-playing of videos, it will only work in muted mode.

```
<video muted autoplay>
</video>
```

i believe you can also start the autoplay with js

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('so_bgvideo_5df3a8b601042').play();
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Nijeesh, the video is in muted mode as per attribute.

Comment: sorry, is that a question or are you suggesting me something ?

Comment: Hi, I have all the attributes suggested already in video element and script... and is still not working for me. Any other ideas please?

Comment: have you tried triggering the play with JavaScript ? also which browser you are having issue with ?

may be take a look at this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764876/html-5-video-autoplay-not-automatically-starting-in-chrome

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `=""` ? not sure if that will do it..

```
<video id="so_bgvideo_5df3a8b601042" class="so_video_bg jquery-background-video is-playing is-visible" loop autoplay playsinline muted data-bgvideo="" poster="https://4f15fi427agh15x4ol42ijp7-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp- content/uploads/video-marketing-1920x1080.jpg" data-bgvideo-fade-in="500" data-bgvideo-pause-after="120" data-bgvideo-show-pause-play="true" data-bgvideo-pause-play-x-pos="right" data-bgvideo-pause-play-y-pos="top" style="min-width: auto; min-height:auto; width: 100%; height: auto; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); transition-duration: 500ms; z-index: 999;">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://mywebsite.com/video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Maybe add this script? this work for me in safari.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('so_bgvideo_5df3a8b601042').play();
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Niroh, the ="" aren't in the code set up. They are added by Chrome and there when I inspected.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered same issue in Safari only and already tried every ways such as adding `playsinline` within video tag which doesn't work. Converting .mp4 video link to BLOB in javascript worked wonder for me.

Initially, define id (e.g. id="ForcePlay") in video source tag:

```
 <video id="ForcePlay" width="500px" height="500px" muted playsinline controls> 
    <source src="url path to your video file" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Create your javascript within your html file, here we convert the video link to blob:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function makeURL(object) {
    return (window.URL) ? window.URL.createObjectURL(object) :    
    window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(object);
  }

  async function display(videoStream){
    var myvideo = document.getElementById('ForcePlay');
    let blob = await fetch(videoStream).then(r => r.blob());
    var videoUrl= makeURL(blob);
    myvideo.src = videoUrl;
  }

  display('url path to your video file');
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a full code working here, just copy and edit :)))

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>page_trouble</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    
  * {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }
 
  
 video#bgvid {

  min-width: auto; min-height: 150vh;
  width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
  background-size: cover;
}
  
  
</style>
    
    
</head>
<body style="background-color:black;">


    <video autoplay loop muted playsinline id="bgvid" >
<source src="fleur_trouble.mp4" type="video/mp4""
<source src="fleur_trouble.webpm" type="video/webpm""


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.