# How to stop camera stream from freezing in Safari browser on an iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, camera

I need to access the iPhone camera and take a screenshot every 10 sec for 40 min.
The methods that I use all work perfectly well on PC and android phones. However, when I execute the code on an iPhone I get the following:
(instead of a stream)

- safari asks if the camera can be accessed (yes)
- safari take a snap of what's happening and the video stream freezes

This one is one example :
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

(to test - just scroll to the middle part - there will be a test button)

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62209408/8635907 - in Apple docs it is explained https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari