# Background video not auto playing on safari browser used svelte to build the website

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari, svelte

I have used svelte to build a website.

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { MetaTags } from 'svelte-meta-tags';
  import Viewport from 'svelte-viewport-info'
  import vi from './assets/videofile.mp4'
  import posterimg from './assets/PosterImage.png'
</script>
<main>
  <video
  autoplay 
  muted 
  loop
  Playsinline
  src={vi}
  poster={posterimg}>
  </video>
</main>
<style>
video 
{
  width: 100%;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
```

After building and deploying the website online

The background video doesn't start playing automatically

Found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325257/html5-video-background-not-playing-safari-on-iphone?#answer-59438421)

```
Safari doesn't allow autoplay of video on these 2 scenarios

    1. when "muted" config not set
    2. when iphone is in battery saving mode or in low battery
```

Some others suggested to include `muted` `autoplay` `Playsinline` which is already done, but still face the same issue

One has suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325257/html5-video-background-not-playing-safari-on-iphone?#answer-59438421?#answer-59660580) to converting `.mp4` video link to `BLOB` in javascript like this

```
 <video id="ForcePlay" width="500px" height="500px" muted playsinline controls> 
    <source src="url path to your video file" type="video/mp4">
 </video>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function makeURL(object) {
    return (window.URL) ? window.URL.createObjectURL(object) :    
    window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(object);
  }

  async function display(videoStream){
    var myvideo = document.getElementById('ForcePlay');
    let blob = await fetch(videoStream).then(r => r.blob());
    var videoUrl= makeURL(blob);
    myvideo.src = videoUrl;
  }

  display('url path to your video file');
</script>
```

Already have `muted` `autoplay` `Playsinline` still same issue

Here's the video [link](https://santhoshnumberone.github.io/videotest/) you can test on safari on your iPhone

How can a convert a file into blob in `svelte` similar what the user suggested as a solution?

Is there any other way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video is encoded by `AV1` which is not supported by `Safari` entire apple ecosystem and `Firefox` on Android [source](https://www.lambdatest.com/web-technologies/av1-support-on-safari-15)